# TS how can I use a class variable inside method?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js, angular-chart

This has been driving me insane. I know it must be something really stupid that I'm missing, but after perusing the forum and furiously searching with google for half a day, I've given up! Please help. This is my first app with Angular and it seems that I'm not great at it.

I have a class var `stats4Graphs` that I receive from a service in .net core 3.1. I know the service works because when I use `stats4Graphs` in the html portion of the component it correctly displays the data. However when I retrieve the data within the function that calls the service I am unable to use the variable, not even for a trivial thing like: `console.log('Labels in: ' + this.stats4Graphs.label);`, as the console shows me "Labels in: undefined" I don't know what else to do.

Here is my model for stats4Graphs

```
    export class Stats4Graphs {
    axisLabels: string[] = [];
    label: string;
    points: number[] = [];
}
```

I don't know if I need to initialize the arrays here or not, it was just one of my desperate attemps to make this work.

Here is my component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Stats4Graphs } from 'src/app/shared/models/stats4-graphs.model';
import { ProfileService } from '../profile.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-engagement-chart',
  templateUrl: './engagement-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./engagement-chart.component.css']
})
export class EngagementChartComponent implements OnInit {  

  public stats4Graphs: Stats4Graphs = new Stats4Graphs();

  // ADD CHART OPTIONS. 
  chartOptions = {
    responsive: true    // THIS WILL MAKE THE CHART RESPONSIVE (VISIBLE IN ANY DEVICE).
  }

  labels =  [];

  // STATIC DATA FOR THE CHART IN JSON FORMAT.
  chartData = [
    {
      label: '',
      data: [] 
    }
  ];

  // CHART COLOR.
  colors = [
    { // 1st Year.
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,0)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(77,83,96,0.2)',
      borderWidth : 2
    }
  ]

  // CHART CLICK EVENT.
  onChartClick(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
  constructor(private profileService: ProfileService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.profileService.getEngagement('UC__8h96Jwsaptaqh227Q9gg')
    .subscribe(stats4Graphs => {
      this.stats4Graphs = stats4Graphs;
    });
    //this.chartData = this.stats.points as any [];
    //this.chartData = this.stats.label as any;
    console.log('Labels in engagement: ' + this.stats4Graphs.label);
    this.labels = this.stats4Graphs.axisLabels as any;
  }

}
```

As you can see what I'm trying to do is a line chart (using Chart.js and ng2-charts) that will display the data contained in `stats4Graphs` I also don't have the slightest idea on how to put the data from `stats4Graphs.points` and `stats4Graphs.label` into `chartData` If you can help me with that it will be great as well.

But now, how do I know that the service actually works? Because I can use it in the component.html and it shows the values that came from the service.

```
<p>{{ stats4Graphs.label }}
        <br />
        {{ stats4Graphs.axisLabels }}
        <br />
        {{ stats4Graphs.points }}
    </p>
```

Thanks in advance for all your help

Comment: The problem is: `this.profileService.getEngagement` is asynchronous. So, your subscription doesn't complete before you immediately try to log the value of that asynchronous call. Move `console.log('Labels in engagement: ' + this.stats4Graphs.label);` into the callback function (right below `this.stats4Graphs = stats4Graphs;`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console.log('Labels in: ' + this.stats4Graphs.label);` is `undefined` because the calling for `this.profileService.getEngagement('UC__8h96Jwsaptaqh227Q9gg')` is asynchronous, so it wasn't finished yet.

The correct way is to put the statement inside the `subscribe`

```
this.profileService.getEngagement('UC__8h96Jwsaptaqh227Q9gg')
  .subscribe(stats4Graphs => {
    this.stats4Graphs = stats4Graphs;

    console.log('Labels in engagement: ' + this.stats4Graphs.label);
    this.labels = this.stats4Graphs.axisLabels as any;
  });
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I'd nitpick. It isn't because the method is asynchronous, as much as that only what is inside of the subscribe method waits on the AJAX call. You could also use a timeout and hope for the best...

Answer (score 0):

You're `console.log`ing outside of the subscription. Since it looks like the `getEngagement()` method of the service returns an Observable, all that you need to do is either set your values inside the subscription, or set the `stats4Graphs` class prop to an `Observable<Stats4Graphs>` and use an `async` pipe within your template, like this:

```
stats4Graph: Observable<Stats4Graph>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.stats4Graph = this.profileService.getEngagement('UC__8h96Jwsaptaqh227Q9gg');
}
```

```
<div *ngIf="stats4Graph | async; let graph">
  <!-- now you can use `graph` as your value of the Observable -->
</div>
```

With this method, you don't have to actively subscribe to the `getEngagement` method of the service, and the `async` pipe automatically handles unsubscribing after your component gets destroyed.